Importing GLB file, no option in dropdown menu
I've sculpted a project in Nomad Sculpt on iPad, and am trying to put it into Blender to render it. I'm following a tutorial on Youtube by @drugfreedave.
I've exported the Nomad file as a .glb. He shows that in the Import dropdown menu, than an option for "glTF 2.0 (.glb/ .gltf)" comes up. That doesn't come up for me though.
How do I import the .glb file?
I am completely new to Blender running 4.2.3 on Mac, and don't understand Python.

I'm not seeing a screenshot of your view in this post.

It sounds as if the addon (which should be built-in) isn't enabled in your Blender version. Go to Edit > Preferences and click the Addons tab.
Type gltf into the top search bar and there should be a glTF 2.0 format entry. Click the checkbox and you should find that the entry appears on the File > Import and Export menus.


